# How to open a json file and parse it to a Json Array (JArray)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm putting together an Web API controller in c# asp.net mvc that opens a Json file which has a Json array that looks like:

```
[ 
  {
    "age": 0, 
    "id": "motorola-xoom-with-wi-fi"
  }, 
  {
    "age": 1, 
    "id": "motorola-xoom"
  },
  ...
  ... 
 ]
```

Then I'm trying to parse it into a Json Array and finally return it as a JsonResult to the API caller.

Comment: Welcome!  That's kewl you answered your own question.  Generally though a question like this might attract comments along the lines of _"any code to show?"_;  _"what research have you done?"_.  Consider expanding on your question a bit. I know this sounds a bit weird considering you have answered it already. [ask].  Wishing you well

Comment: can you explain what part of the question is not clear? i added tags to give context so it's understood im talking about c#, asp.net mvc. I had a hard time finding any guidance on how to do what i asked so i decided to post it for others that run into the same challenge. i will try to add some more info.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
// GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        // read JSON directly from a file
        using (StreamReader file = System.IO.File.OpenText(@"wwwroot/phones/phones.json"))
        {
            var jArray = JArray.Parse(file.ReadToEnd());
            return Json(jArray); 
        }
    }
```

Cheers!